# Need to find out, an application has installed already on the same device?

Tags: android

I need to implement trial period on my application. Once trial period is over,If user tries to uninstall and install the application again, for this case I had write one file on sdcard, if the user re install the application. When they open the application I had shown activation key prompt.

If the user delete the file,they can re install and use the application normally. How to solve this case. Is there any other way to hold the application install details in android device.

Note:
My application is a offline application.It won't need to connect with internet.(So there is no way to register with  server).

Comment: You can't do it without a server and an Internet connection. Even if you save this file inside the restricted `/data/data/<your_package_name>`, a user with a rooted device can edit/remove this file as they wish. Bottom line: There's no fool-proof solution by doing it locally on the device.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but I need to know, Is there any way like registry ? That is why I had raised this question.

Comment: No. Your best bet is using a server for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take of it this way. Everything you store on your phone will be able to get edited/removed/added. The best approach to this kind of problems is to use a webservice to register a device and check it's register date. However since your application is offline there is no way to do it foolproof.